# What service do I use for "web service" in Qualtrics?

Tags: http, qualtrics

In a Qualtrics survey, I want to use the "web service" feature to send the response to a question to a server where I would compute something for out of a set of reponses and send it back to the survey. I assume I would do that with the POST and GET methods respectively.

What would a good web service be? In other words, how would I specify the URL field in the screenshot below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The web service is the script on server that performs the task and returns the desired result.  For example, if your domain was "example.com" and the script was "myscript.php" then the url would be https://example.com/myscript.php.

Whether you send a get or post request depends on how the script is written to receive the input data.

The output of the script (i.e., the data you want return to the survey) should be in json format.